# How to prevent MySQLi from automatic sorting in a query?

Tags: mysqli

I have a table **master** where there song details are stored against their ids.

I have another table **playlist** that is actually a user playlist and only ids from the first table are inserted selectively here.

So the first table holds data like:
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10..........112,113........500 etc along with other fields.

The second table only have selective ids.

45, 7, 98, 83, 6, 65, 8, 234, 51, 78.

Now I am running the following query

```
 SELECT * FROM master WHERE id IN (SELECT * FROM playlist)
```

but the result set returned comes sorted as

6, 7, 8, 45, 51, 65,78, 83, 98, 234 with their corresponding details.

How do I prevent this automatic sorting?

Comment: So you want them to be sorted based on playlist sequence?

Comment: Yes actually if the result is returned as they are in the db, that will be fine. Currently it being auto-sorted by MySQL.

Comment: I managed to solve it. Added a column serial no to the table. And used the following query. select * from audiomaster a inner join playlist_top10 b on b.audioid = a.id order by b.serialno

Answer (score 0):

Added a column serialno to the table playlist.

Then used the following query.

```
select * from audiomaster a inner join playlist_top10 b on b.audioid = a.id order by b.serialno
```

The rows now are always sorted in the order they are meant to be.